# Extreme value theorem for functions defined on weakly compact sets.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, extreme-value-theorem

So I start this by saying that I know very littler about topology and the related topics in this question, so  this question may be trivial/ill-possed, etc.

I've read in many places that it is a well known result in functional analysis that a Banach space $X$ is reflexive if and only if the unit ball is weakly compact (compact in the weak topology).

So assume we have a real separable Hilbert space $H$ (this space is a reflexive Banach space), and consider the unit sphere $S=\{f\in H:\|f\|=1\}$, then $S$ is weakly compact.

I would like to use (some generalization of...) Weierstrass extreme value theorem to prove that a continuous function $F:S\to \mathbb R$ attains a maximum.

---

A little bit of background, here $H$ is a quantum Hilbert space, $S$ is the family of "quantum states". Then I wanted to prove that a (continuous) function of the quantum states will attain a maximum.

---

Is it possible to do something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F: S \to \Bbb R$ is continuous (where $S$ has the weak topology, and $\Bbb R$ the standard topology), a standard fact in topology is that $F[S]$ is also compact in $\Bbb R$ and by standard facts about the reals a compact set like $F[S]$ has a maximum and a mimumum. QED.

So a combination of a standard "compactness preserving" fact and properties of the reals. Both are easily shown from definitions.

Comment: It might help to know that every norm-continuous linear functional is automatically weakly continuous.

Comment: Great! do you know of some good book treating this? I would like to fully understand the implications of this fact.

Comment: There is also a "one-sided" version of Ruy's comment: Every norm lower semicontinuous convex function is automatically weakly lower semicontinuous. This is helpful if you only want to prove the existence of a minimum (replace convex by concave and lower semicontinuous by upper semicontinuous for maxima).

Comment: I think I've made a stupid mistake, I was considering the unit sphere, but the James' theorem regarding reflexive Banach spaces talks about the unit ball, so I don't think weak compactness holds for $S$ right?

Comment: @Chaos the unit sphere is a closed subspace of the unit ball, so it’s also weakly compact.